# Is there a way to refer to all parents/children that are nested inside a div?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

This function shows/hides child elements by class, but it currently requires specifying each parent element separately. How can I modify it so that it will trigger the relevant children, grandchildren, etc. in  without having to specify the `id` of each  and  I want to include?

I've posted a fiddle with a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/YvMwL/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#filterOptions li a').click(function() {
    var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');        

    if(ourClass == 'all') {
        $('#content').children('div.item').show();
        $('#list').children('li.item').show();  
    }
    else {          
        $('#content').children('div:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide();
        $('#list').children(':not(li.' + ourClass + ')').hide();
        $('#content').children('div.' + ourClass).show();
        $('#list').children('li.' + ourClass).show();
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Not sure if I've understood the problem correctly, but if you want to get all descendents for something (i.e. not just children but their children as well, etc) then use `find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: In this example I'm trying to get the <div>'s that are children of  #content, and/or <li> which are grandchildren of #content (and show/hide any of their descendants). I'm not sure how I would apply 'find' to that - would you mind showing me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's two issues here. Firstly, the items you want to select are of different tag names, and secondly they are at different levels (`div`s are children and `li`s are grandchildren). Happily you already have a way to refer to all these items: the `.item` class.

So, if we use the `find` method together with this new selector approach, then we can modify your jsFiddle thus:

```
    if (ourClass == 'all')
    {
        // show all our items
        $('#content').find('.item').show();
    }
    else
    {
        // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide();

        // show all elements that do share ourClass
        $('#content').find('.item.' + ourClass).show();
    }
```

My fork is here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/4/

Comment: That works perfectly :-) btw - You accidentally included the link to my original fiddle so I changed your link to a new fiddle with your code ;-)

Comment: :-D Thank you so much for your help :-) Now if I could only figure out how to use data-attributes instead of classes I might actually be able to take a break this weekend ;-)

Comment: Well, you should take at least one day off - get a break and come back to it `:)`

Comment: I probably should, but I won't be able to relax until I feel like I have a handle on this ;-)